# What FPS game does this screenshot (of a Skorpion SMG) from the Dxtory features page belong to?

Tags: game-identification

While looking at the [features page for the Dxtory movie capture tool](http://exkode.com/dxtory-features-en.html) I noticed this image:

[image: Screenshot of weapon labeled Skorpion]

<sup>Source: http://exkode.com/images/fps.png</sup>

It looks like the weapon is labeled "Skorpion" (which is a [real weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0korpion)) in the lower right along with some other text (though I can't make out the rest of the text).

I tried to do a reverse image search on TinEye but the only other sites which came up in the search were in a foreign language and used the image in the context of the Dxtory tool rather than the game itself.

I would guess this is one of the many Call of Duty games, though I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Performing a reverse image search didn't pull up any results except for the webpage the OP got the image

Comment: @Wondercricket I would guess the downvoters thought the answer to the question was obvious since CoD is a popular franchise. It's just not obvious to me because I've been out of the online FPS world for a couple of years (and I didn't play the CoD franchise even then -- I played Killzone and Battlefield instead).

Comment: @null :::cough cough:::: as you should

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I dont know what map that is, but I'm 99.99% sure its from **Call of Duty Black Ops 2**.

[image]

Here's another screenshot from that game with the same weapon and similar HUD.

Comment: The map is called Magma from the second DLC, Uprising.

Comment: Thats why I dont know it, I was too cheap to ever buy the DLC maps :p

Comment: Yep, googling the Japanese text does indicate that it's the "Magma" map. Here's a Kotaku article that shows the post office sign head-on, if it's useful: https://kotaku.com/the-bizarre-japanese-of-call-of-duty-black-ops-iis-ne-474580863